# Am centering content vertically using css, how to remove empty space?

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

You can see my result in the image below. The red box is vertically centered, which I intended. But the red box has a lot of empty space. I don't know where it comes from. How can I remove it so that the "real" content is centered?

[image]

This is my HTML

```
<ion-view view-title="{{ 'WELCOME' | translate }}">
  <ion-content class="padding cust-vertical-center">
    <form class="list">
      <label class="item item-input">
        <input type="text" class="text-align-center" placeholder="{{ 'EMAIL' | translate }}" ng-model="credentials.email"  autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" spellcheck="false">
      </label>
      <label class="item item-input">
        <input type="password" class="text-align-center" placeholder="{{ 'PASSWORD' | translate }}" ng-model="credentials.password"  autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off">
      </label>
      <button class="button button-block button-stable" type="submit" ng-click="okLogin()">{{ 'LOGIN' | translate }}</button>
    </form>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

This is my CSS

```
.cust-vertical-center {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

  width: 100%;
  height: auto;

  background: red;
}
```

Comment: Please, share real html, not preprocessed codes without sense, because is more useful if you share a working fiddle. take a look: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is right and there's not "empty space" as in the picture you posted. So the problem is somewhere else in the code. Probably some css property of the parents.

You can check it out the code in this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/556GL/105/)** with ionic installed.

Your css (as I need to input some code):

```
.cust-vertical-center {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background: red;
}
```

Comment: For other seeing this topic: My case is maybe specific to Ionic. The following solution worked in my case: .cust-center-ion-content3 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

Answer (score 0):

You centering whole `.cust-vertical-center` element (which has red background) and is not 100% height inside html document, not its content, so other part of document is white. If you want all document background to be red you should add  `background` style to `body` or `html`.

Here's [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aq8z1mow/) with easiest solution.